# How to wait for the function to end before start the function again

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to wait for my first function to end before I can click "Click me" button again. I have been searching for a way to let my function end first before I can let the new function run again.

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

setTimeout(function() {
  myFunction();
}, 3000);

var id = null;

function myFunction() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");
  var pos = 0;
  clearInterval(id);
  id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#myAnimation {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript addEventListener()</h2>

<button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>

<div id="myContainer">
  <div id="myAnimation"></div>
```

Comment: "_first function to end_" here means the timed out `myFunction` call? What is the purpose of the button? You're starting the interval anyway, making a small difference within 10 msecs isn't detactable by a visitor.

Comment: A function inside a function is really not recommended. Just call the function at the end of your first function when they are not nested :)

Comment: check for the state of a flag at the beginning of your click event handler as the condition before performing something and toggle that flag only when the action finished perfoming

Answer (score 0):

You should disable your button during your function.

edited: If you don't want to disable maybe with a lock.

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

setTimeout(function() {
  myFunction();
}, 3000);

var id = null;
var lock = false;

function myFunction() {
  
  if(!lock){
  lock = true;
  var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");
  var pos = 0;
  clearInterval(id);
  
  id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
      lock = false;
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
 }
}
```

```css
#myContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#myAnimation {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript addEventListener()</h2>

<button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>

<div id="myContainer">
  <div id="myAnimation"></div>
```

edited: **Try making your animation with CSS it's a better practice.**

Comment: I edited it the right place for disable = false is after the clearInterval()

Comment: We answered your question mark it as resolved and create a new one if needed.

Comment: Nice one you got me 

Answer (score 0):

If we disable and enable the button in the correct place, it will work quite nicely

I also cleaned up the code a bit to make it more contained.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  const elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");
  let id = null;
  let pos = 0;
  const frame = () => {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
      myBtn.disabled = false;
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }

  const myFunction = () => {
    pos = 0;
    clearInterval(id);
    id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    myBtn.disabled = true;
  }

  id = setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
  myBtn.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
});
```

```css
#myContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#myAnimation {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript addEventListener()</h2>

<button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>

<div id="myContainer">
  <div id="myAnimation"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a first implementation you could disable the button before you start the animation, and you only enable it after you are done

```js
var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn")
myBtn.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

setTimeout(function() {
  myFunction();
}, 3000);

var id = null;

function myFunction() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");
  var pos = 0;
  clearInterval(id);
  id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  // disable the button
  myBtn.disabled = true;

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
      // enable the button again
      myBtn.disabled = false;

    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}

#myAnimation {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript addEventListener()</h2>

<button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>

<div id="myContainer">
  <div id="myAnimation"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let sum = 0;
const x = 10;
async function firstFunction() {
  for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    sum = sum + i;
  }
  return sum;
}
async function secondFunction() {
  await firstFunction();
  console.log('After firstFunction executed sum is', sum);
}
secondFunction();
```

Comment: Please use OP's own code, add some description and [format the code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or use the  [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.